# Is it possible to join a hive table with oracle table?

Tags: oracle, join, hadoop, hive

I have a problem in writing Query using [HiveQL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual).

Is it possible to join a hive table with oracle table?
if yes how? 
if no why?

Answer (score 0):

To access data stored in your Hive tables, including joining on them, you will need [Oracle Big Data connector](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37231_01/doc.20/e36961/sqlch.htm#CIHCIIHD).

From the documentation:

> Using Oracle SQL Connector for HDFS, you can use Oracle Database to access and analyze data residing in HDFS files or a Hive table. You can also query and join data in HDFS or a Hive table with other database-resident data. If required, you can also load data into the database using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You first access Hive tables from Oracle Database via external tables . The The external table definition is generated automatically from the Hive table definition. Hive table data can be accessed by querying this external table. The data can be queried with Oracle SQL and joined with other tables in the database.
You can use the Hive table  that uses data and can access this Hive table from Oracle Database.